# Use subform record set as domain argument in DAvg()

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, aggregate-functions, subform

Is it possible to use a subform's 'current' record set as the `domain` argument to `DAvg()` (etc.)?

Basically, I have a subform that displays a subset of records from a query. I would like to run `DAvg()` over this subset. This is how I've gotten around it:

```
=DAvg([FieldToAvg], [SubformQuery], "ChildField=Forms.MasterForm.MasterField And FieldToAvg > 0")
```

but what I actually want is something like:

```
=DAvg([FieldToAvg], [SubformCurrentlyDisplayedData], "FieldToAvg > 0")
```

Is this possible in Access 2007?

Comment: The answer to your actual question is NO, you can't pass a recordset to a domain aggregate function. For a possible solution, see my comment on @Remou's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you do not want to use a subform footer, hidden or otherwise, to do this? It is the simplest way.

In a textbox:

```
=Avg([SomeField])
```

Comment: Yes, I need to exclude some of the displayed records from the average. That's why I'm using `DAvg()`.

Comment: You can use IIf() to create a column in your subform's Recordsource that includes only the values you want to average and then use that with @Remou's suggestion.